# How to a add draw offer to a PGN

Tags: draw, pgn

Does PGN have any annotations for draw offers? Just adding `=` after a move doesn't seem to work everywhere. Among the standard NAGs there is `$10` (a drawish or even position) which translates as `=`; or I can use a comment. But I am wondering whether there's a specific way of adding a draw offer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no symbol for a draw offer. Just add a comment {draw offered}

Comment: It's weird as FIDE rules says `The offer of a draw shall be noted by each player on his scoresheet with a symbol. (=)` and yet it hasn't been implemented in PGN. Thanks!

Comment: The FIDE rule is more recent than the PGN standard, which was written in 1994.

Comment: @Samurai thanks for sharing the fide rule!

Comment: I just implemented in [#57](https://github.com/mliebelt/pgn-parser/issues/57) of my pgn-parser that recording of a draw offer. Yes, it is not part of the spec, but it is reasonable that the rules given by FIDE should be respected.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer should be, that the format has to include the parentheses. So a draw offer in some PGN notation should look like:

```
1. e4 e5 (=)
```

So black is offering a draw after his first move.

See the example game at the [end of section C](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf) that looks like:

> 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. d4 exd4 4. e5 Ne4 5. Qxd4 d5 6. exd6e.p. Nxd6 7. Bg5 Nc6 8. Qe3+3 Be7 9. Nbd2 0-0 10. 0-0-0 Re8 11. Kb1 (=)

PS: Shameless plug: I have just implemented that in my pgn-parser, see [#57](https://github.com/mliebelt/pgn-parser/issues/57).

Comment: Tried to use that notation in lichess (analysis or study), and of course it fails. So yes, there seems to be not so many implementations of that rule of chess.